TextFormField Error message on validation - Flutter
I have implemented SignIn screen in which I created customTextFormField cause I need to use it in another screen also but my concern is when someone enter the value in email field it will show error in password field even if nothing has been entered yet. Here's a image:

SignIn:
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignIn> createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final _sformkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Sign In',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Form(
                key: _sformkey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    //Email field
                    CustomTextFormField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Please enter email address";
                        } else if (!RegExp(
                            r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+$')
                            .hasMatch(value)) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 4),
                    //Password field
                    CustomTextFormField(
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'The email or password you have entered is incorrect.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    //Sign In Button
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (_sformkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/nextpage');
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        //SignIn Button
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

CustomTextFormField:
class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextFormField(
      {super.key,
        required this.controller,
        required this.hintText,
        required this.keyboardType,
        required this.validator});

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validator;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        validator: validator,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400, width: 1.5),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red.shade900, width: 2),
          ),
          errorMaxLines: 2,
        ),
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have also tried AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction to prevent this but I don't understand what silly mistake I am making. I just want that if someone enter the wrong value in email and password it will show error otherwise it will clear the error message.

Try validator like this - final String? Function(String?)? validator;

Tried it but got same results.

remove this line from the From widget  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,

You have used AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction for whole Form widget remove it first, if you want autovalidate mode then call it seprete textfield

@RavindraS.Patil Now I got it I used AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction for whole Form widget. Thank you

Replace the line autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction from your Form Widget for autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled and it should solve your problem since you manually trigger the validate methods when you tab the signin button.

Thanks for your response but when I set it AutovalidateMode.disabled then it will show error message onSubmit of keyboard or not the actual result that I want.
